# Execute command on remote server via ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am attempting to execute a command on a remote linux server via an ssh command on a local server like this:

> ssh myremoteserver 'type ttisql'

where ttisql is an executable on the path of my remote machine.

The result of running this is:

> bash: line 0: type: ttisql: not found

When I simply connect first and do:

> ssh myremoteserver

and then enter the command:

> [myuser@myremoteserver~]$: type ttisql

I get back the path of the ttisql exe as I would expect.

The odd thing is that when I execute the first command in my beta environment it works as expected and returns the path of the exe.  In the beta scenario, machine A is connecting to remote machine B but both machines are onsite and the ssh command connects to the remote machine quickly.

The problem is encountered in our production environment when machine A is local and machine B is offsite and the ssh command takes a second or two to connect.

The only difference I can see is the time it takes the production ssh to connect.  The path on the remote system is correct since the command works if entered after the initial connection.

Can anyone help me understand why this simple command would work in one environment and not the other?  Could the problem be related to the time it takes to connect via ssh?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `PATH` is setup differently when your shell is interactive (= when you are logged in on the server), and when not interactive (running commands with `ssh`).

Look into the rc files used by your shell, for example `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` (depends on your system). If you set `PATH` at the right place, then `ttisql` can work when you run it via `ssh`.

Another solution is to use the absolute path of `ttisql`, then it will not depend on your `PATH` setup.

Comment: Updating the .bashrc and .bash_profile files did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An additional hangup for me was the difference between `ssh remote echo $PATH` and `ssh remote 'echo $PATH'`. The tick marks were key.

Comment: That's cool @fenkerbb! btw the common name for those in your example is single quotes ;-)

Answer (score 26):

The environment can be different in a non-interactive session (`ssh command`) from an interactive session (`ssh`, then `command`). Try `echo $PATH` in both cases.

```
ssh myremoteserver 'echo $PATH'
```

vs

```
ssh myremoteserver
[myuser@myremoteserver~]$: echo $PATH
```

If they differ, look in all startup script for some differentiated behavior based on `$PS1` or `$-`