# Can't run chef-solo command through ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh, chef-infra, chef-solo

In the case when I first ssh to the server and then run command, it executes successfully

```
root@chef:~# chef-solo -v
Chef: 11.10.0
```

But when I try to run it like this

```
 ssh root@188.xxx.xxx.xxx -t -C "chef-solo -c /var/chef/solo.rb"
```

I receive an error:

```
bash: chef-solo: command not found
```

Why is this happening, and how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Are any of your cookbooks managing the `$PATH`. It's likely that `chef-solo` was in your path and now isn't.

Comment: yep. Like this in solo.rb

    `cookbook_path File.expand_path("../cookbooks", __FILE__)`
    `json_attribs File.expand_path("../node.json", __FILE__)`

Comment: That's not what I mean. On the target system - are any of those cookbooks managing a bash.rc or /etc/profile?

Comment: No they are not. Indeed I can run them through VPS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still matter of `$PATH` and ssh - **not** chef-solo. Interactive and non-interactive sessions not necessarily have same value for the `$PATH` variable. Same ssh problem is described [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894962/execute-command-on-remote-server-via-ssh). You may also check [GNU bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) to have deeper insight of (non-)interactive and (non-)login shells. To shorten, solution would be one of the following:

1. Run chef-solo using absolute path. Here's how your command **might** look like:

   - ssh root@188.xxx.xxx.xxx -t -C "/**usr/local/ruby/bin**/chef-solo -c /var/chef/solo.rb"
2. Tune the .bash configuration files to load same `$PATH` variable for both interactive and non-interactive shells.

Note: **To find out what's the absolute path**, login to the machine via ssh and run `which chef-solo` (Don't know how experienced you are with linux. Sorry if I'm underestimating your knowledge)

Comment: You was right. Here I found more detailed answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal . And in my particular situation I need to remove this line from `~/.bashrc` `# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`