# Trouble running remote comand via SSH that local machine doesn't know

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a remote machine and run a command, and get the STDOUT.

```
ssh user@host 'uptime'
```

Works fine and gives me the uptime for the remote host.

```
ssh user@host 'device-specific-command'
```

Gives me 'command not found'.

All I can think of is the device-specific-command is unknown to the local machine. Is there any way I can get around this and run the remote command from the remote host?

Comment: Are you putting the entire command including arguments inside quotes? If so, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been asked there -> [Execute command on remote server via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894962/execute-command-on-remote-server-via-ssh)

I think that it is the same issue!

ssh executes the command on the remote server, so it is the path of the remote that matters. Try to put the path to your utility directly in your ssh command -> ssh user@remote '/path/to/utility'

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I believe that particular q/a is based around the $PATH on the local host not including the ttisql utility, as that is what s/he was trying to run on the remote host. The utility I am endeavoring to invoke remotely is not present on my local host.

Comment: @user2978190: It is irrelevant that it is not present on your local host.

Comment: ssh executes the command on the remote server, so it is the path of the remote that matters.

Try to put the path to your utility directly in your ssh command -> ssh user@remote '/path/to/utility'