# Execute script on server A to get data of server B

Tags: shell, for-loop, ssh, server

Sorry for my question, but i'm a beginner. I search how to execute a script on a server A, to get some folders name on server B. So i created a small `script.sh` on server A like this :

```
TRANSFERTDIR=/usr/share/folder/simplystorage

#Appel SSH pour se connecter au serveur local
ssh root@myip -p2222

for user in $(find $TRANSFERTDIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n")
do
    echo $user
done
```

When i executed the script, i'm connected to server B and it's normal because there is ssh connexion... So how can i execute my script on my server A and get data of the server B without changed server (stay on server A) ? Or how can i do it with another solution ?

I hope you understand what i mean...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute command on remote server via ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894962/execute-command-on-remote-server-via-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `ssh` command a command to run on the remote server:

```
TRANSFERTDIR=/usr/share/folder/simplystorage
ssh root@myip -p2222 bash -c 'printf "%s\n" '"$TRANSFERTDIR"'/*/'
```